# Mapping json data to java objects in a proper way-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I am working on an endless running game with levels.I want to place obstacles for the first level.I want do it with json,but having difficulties because I am trying json parsing for the first time.

I created a json file like this:

```
{
"screen1":
[
{"name":"rock","position":"middle","distance":"400","speed":"0"}
],
"screen2":  
[
      {"name":"snake","position":"up","distance":"100","speed":"0"},
      {"name":"watersnake","position":"up","distance":"800","speed":"0"}
],
"screen3":
 [
      {"name":"rock","position":"middle","distance":"400","speed":"0"},
      {"name":"gorilla","position":"middle","distance":"500","speed ":"0"},
      {"name":"crow","position":"up","distance":"200","speed":"0"}

],

"screen4":
[
    {"name":"crocodile","position":"up","distance":"600","speed":"0"},
    {"name":"gap","position":"up","distance":"700","speed":"0"},
    {"name":"cloud","position":"up","distance":"300","speed":"0"}

],
"screen5":
[
{"name":"gorilla","position":"middle","distance":"500","speed ":"0"}
]
}
```

Actually I divided entire moving background to 5 screens.For each screen,I want to place obstacles as specified in the json file.

For that I want to map parsed json to java object.

So I created a method like this for parsing:

```
 public void loadLevelJson(String fileName,String entryName)
{
        JsonValue jsonValue = new JsonReader().parse(Gdx.files.internal(fileName));
        JsonValue objList = jsonValue.get(entryName);
            //  System.out.println("name:" + objList);
                if (entryName.equals("screen2")){
                    System.out.println("____________"+entryName);
                for(JsonValue value : objList.iterator())
                {
                      if(value.getString("name").equals("rock"))
                      {
                          rockSpeed=value.getFloat("speed");
                          rockpos=value.getString("position");
                          rockX=value.getFloat("distance");

                          if(value.getString("position").equals("middle"))
                              rockY=Constants.BIG_ROCK_Y;
                      }

                      if(value.getString("name").equals("snake"))
                      {
                          snakeSpeed=value.getFloat("speed");
                          snakePos=value.getString("position");
                          snakeX=value.getFloat("distance");
                          if(value.getString("position").equals("up"))
                              snakeY=Constants.SNAKE_Y;
                      }
                      if(value.getString("name").equals("watersnake"))
                      {
                          w_snakeSpeed=value.getFloat("speed");
                          w_snakePos=value.getString("position");
                          w_snakeX=value.getFloat("distance");
                          if(value.getString("position").equals("down"))
                              w_snakeY=Constants.W_SNAKE_Y;
                      }
                      if(value.getString("name").equals("gorilla"))
                      {
                          gorillaSpeed=value.getFloat("speed");
                          gorillaPos=value.getString("position");
                          gorillaX=value.getFloat("distance");
                          if(value.getString("position").equals("middle"))
                              gorillaY=Constants.GORILLA_Y;
                      }
                      if(value.getString("name").equals("crow"))
                      {
                          crowSpeed=value.getFloat("speed");
                          crowPos=value.getString("position");
                          crowX=value.getFloat("distance");
                          if(value.getString("position").equals("up"))
                              crowY=Constants.CROW_Y;
                      }

                      if(value.getString("name").equals("gap"))
                      {
                          gapSpeed=value.getFloat("speed");
                          gapPos=value.getString("position");
                          gapX=value.getFloat("distance");
                          if(value.getString("position").equals("down"))
                              gapY=Constants.GAP_Y;
                      }
                      if(value.getString("name").equals("cloud"))
                      {
                          cloudSpeed=value.getFloat("speed");
                          cloudPos=value.getString("position");
                          cloudX=value.getFloat("distance");
                          if(value.getString("position").equals("up"))
                              cloudY=Constants.CLOUD_Y;
                      }
                      if(value.getString("name").equals("cloud"))
                      {
                          crocodileSpeed=value.getFloat("speed");
                          crocodilePos=value.getString("position");
                          crocodileX=value.getFloat("distance");
                          if(value.getString("position").equals("down"))
                              crocodileY=Constants.CROCODILE_Y;
                      }
                }
}

}
```

But I am really getting a hard time on how to parse these things with each screen and obstacles to map to screen and object classes created.Fully confused because I am using json for the first time.

It would be very helpful if someone gives some idea to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to achieve this. Maybe do some research into libgdx json using java collections. How you end up structuring your code is really up to you. We don't know the details of your code or how you'll need to use the data.

Maybe start simpler, get something working and then expand from there once you're more comfortable. Perhaps break your json obstacles into individual files per screen to start. What you're then left with could (just an example) utilize the List interface.

Again, as an example, if you had an Obstacle class (all code just informational, don't even know if it compiles)

```
pulic class Obstacle {

    private String name;
    private String position;
    private int distance;
    private int speed;
}
```

use this to instantiate an object for each obstacle in a level. Then wherever you're doing your json parsing/need the obstacles, have something like

```
...
//fileName contains only obstacles for one screen, not all of them
ArrayList<Obstacle> obstacles = json.fromJson(ArrayList.class, Obstacle.class, Gdx.files.internal(fileName));
```

That would give you an ArrayList of obstacles in play for that specific level, but how you use it is up to you. Like I said above, many different options but you'd have to tailor to your requirements. Using the Map interface might make more sense, for example, to use the obstacle name as the key (or maybe not - up to you). To have all obstacles for all screens loaded at once may lend itselfs to Lists of Lists (or List of Map, etc... ). More complex, but if you get the above working, you can then play around with ever increasing complexity and refactor to suit your needs.

Again, just typed the above off the top of my head, so syntax may be a little off.

**Edit to add**:

Updating after some of your comments: As I said above, there are many ways to go about it, all depending on your data and how you want to use it. The Collections Framework should provide you all you need, and using the example I provided for json, you should be able to parse from files. The more "nesting" you have, the more complex the json. Thus, why I suggest starting slower, or breaking screen obstacles into each individual class.

If you've created classes for the obstacles, then the json in my original answer would automatically read it into an ArrayList for you. One element in the list for each obstacle.

(Again, all this code off the top of my head, could have syntax errors)

Another option may be to use the Map interface, maybe a HashMap. Use the "name" as the key, and the value would be the obstacle object (no need to include the name in the object). Something like

```
Map<Obstacle> obstacles = new HashMap<String, Obstacle>().
```

Now to get an individual obstacle, you access the map, asking for the obstacle by name and you'll get your obstacle class (read up on the collections framework API).

You can of course nest your obstacles into another collection, which represents your screens. Something like

```
List<HashMap<String, Obstacle>> screenObstacles = new ....
```

So if you read your json obstacles one screen at a time (like in my original example) into variable aVar, you should be able to do

```
screenObstacles.add(aVar);
```

Then retrieve as needed.

```
Map<Obstacle> obstacles = screenObstacles.get(screenNumber); //screenNumber is screen you are on, ex 0/1/2/...
Obstacle obstacle = obstacles.get(GORILLA_NAME); // GORILLA_NAME is a string "gorilla"

//or loop through all obstacles for a given screen and do something with them

for (Obstacle obstacle : obstacles) {
    //something amazing goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!The problem now I am facing is with screens.I have to generalize the code such that It should take screen number automatically for each level.Now I am just trying with each screen in an improper way.For that  should I use ArrayList?It would be very helpful if u elaborate the answer a bit.I edited code in my question.

Comment: The code you posted has hard coded obstacles variables, repetitive code for reading the json and is not easy to extend (what if you add a new obstacle?). So unsure what you mean by generalizing your code. Unsure if I can be of more help as really don't know every little thing you're trying to do. The example I posted shows how to quickly read a screen's worth of json. So extrapolate that and either read each json when you have a new screen, or loop through all your sreens' json once and create a list of the list in my example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!Actually I was trying out something my own, without proper knowledge about json and its usage .Now I did some research and I  would like to follow your example as I feel that it the proper way.

Comment: I already created classes for obstacles individually with the same properties you mentioned in the example.like rock,crow,crocodile etc.Now I am confused of how to create arrayList for those obstacles.

Comment: I did update my answer with some more suggestions. More "theory", but also some code snippets to show what I meant. Understanding collections, even at a higher level along with some of the API is needed. But there is lots of good documentation/examples out there if you look.